# Zend Framework - Update a Database row with WHERE and AND

Tags: php, zend-framework

To use `where` in a MySQL table row update in Zend Framework I have something like:

```
public function updateBySiteId(array $data, $id) {
        $table = $this->gettable();

        $where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('site_id = ?', $id);

        return $table->update($data, $where);
    }
```

and this, I expect, gives me something like...

```
UPDATE foo SET ponies = 'sparkly' WHERE site_id = '1'
```

But what if I want to create the following:

```
UPDATE foo SET ponies = 'sparkly' WHERE site_id = '1' AND type = 'zombie'
```

In the manual I don't see how to do this with quoteInto (or quote or some other safe method... which could just mean I'm looking in the wrong place but... *sigh*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Since the table update() method
>   proxies to the database adapter 
>   update()  method, the second argument
>   can be an array of SQL expressions.
>   The expressions are combined as
>   Boolean terms using an AND operator.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html

```
$data = array(
'updated_on'      => '2007-03-23',
'bug_status'      => 'FIXED'
);
$where[] = "reported_by = 'goofy'";
$where[] = "bug_status = 'OPEN'";
$n = $db->update('bugs', $data, $where);
```

Resulting SQL is:

```
UPDATE "bugs" SET "update_on" = '2007-03-23', "bug_status" = 'FIXED' WHERE ("reported_by" = 'goofy') AND ("bug_status" = 'OPEN')
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.update

Comment: That did it. I read that bit in the manual but created the array incorrectly: $where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto(array('site_id = ?' => $id, 'foo' => $bar));